# How to add specific system app while provisionned device using QR

Tags: android, device-owner

I tried to provisioned my android device using QR code. The QR code contains all the information concerning my DPC so that it becomes device owner. Everything is working except one thing. I would like to have my own system apps after provisioned. I filled in this file with all the applications I want: frameworks\base\core\res\res\values\vendor_required_apps_managed_device.xml
However, whatever I am filling in this file, I am getting only some Google system app. How is it working?

Comment: Have you tried using this in your QR code? "android.app.extra.PROVISIONING_LEAVE_ALL_SYSTEM_APPS_ENABLED":true

Comment: Yes I tried. It shows all the application in the main screen. Not just the ones in frameworks\base\core\res\res\values\vendor_required_apps_managed_device.xml